# Do I have to use mysql_real_escape_string if I bind parameters?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I have the following code:

```
function dbPublish($status)
{
 global $dbcon, $dbtable;

 if(isset($_GET['itemId']))
 {
  $sqlQuery = 'UPDATE ' . $dbtable . ' SET active = ? WHERE id = ?';
  $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sqlQuery);
  $stmt->bind_param('ii', $status, $_GET['itemId']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
 }
}
```

Do I need to mysql_real_escape_string in this case or am i okay?

Comment: Note that only parameters are immune to SQL injection; any variable interpolated directly into the query string (such as `$dbtable`) is a potential vector, if its value comes from user input. Of course, things like table and column names should never come directly from user input.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, you don't have to escape value yourself *(i.e. no you don't need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string`)*, when you are using prepared statements : the DB engine will do that itself.

*(Actually, if you were calling `mysql_real_escape_string` and using bound parameters, your strings would get escaped twice -- which would not be great : you'd end up with escaping characters everywhere...)*

As a sidenote : your values are passed as integers *(as indicated by the `'ii'`)*, so you wouldn't have to call `mysql_real_escape_string`, even if you were not using prepared statements : as its name indicates, this function is used to escape... strings.

For integers, I generally just use [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) to make sure the data I inject into my SQL queries really are integers.

*(But, as you are using prepared queries, once again, you don't have to do that kind of escaping yourself)*

Answer (score 1):

No, you must not. Combining the two would result
in visible escape characters showing up in your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dbPublish($status)    
{    
 global $dbcon, $dbtable;    

 if(isset($_GET['itemId']))    
 {    
  $sqlQuery = 'UPDATE ' . $dbtable . ' SET active = ? WHERE id = ?';    
  $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sqlQuery);    
  $stmt->bind_param('ii', $status, $_GET['itemId']);    
  $stmt->execute();    
  $stmt->close();    
 }    
}
```